# Creating group header fields in SSRS report with child values based on existing crystal report

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-tablix, crystal-reports-xi

Currently I am upgrading a crystal report as an SSRS format. But this report has been tricky in which it has multiple group headers that have sub headers and data associated to them.
I have been researching for about an hour or so attempting different solutions to replicate the report and the solution that I thought would work below seems to be close but I can't get the fields to be a stepped as how it is in the crystal report where the rows are stacked neatly with data presented for each row.

Solution found online that is pretty close but does not have a result of data stepped:

1. Insert Table
2. First field make a parent row group and have "add group header" checked
3. Right click on parent field just created and select to insert "new row outside below"
4. Drag over sub field name
5. With data fields needing to be present under sub field I added those as child fields

Images of my work:

[image: http://i1243.photobucket.com/albums/gg554/tyler12fromspace/Crystal%20Image%201_zps3qe06s1r.png]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some trials runs I finally figured out the setup:

1. Insert Table

   2. Right click on "Details" in row groups
   3. Add parent group of you first header row in your report (mine was scheduled ship date)
   4. Right click details and add another parent for your second header row as so its above "Details" but below your first parent group
   5. Now things may look strange since you have two columns with your parents
   6. Now what you want to do is have only one column in your table that consists of three rows
   7. What you will now do is copy the bracket values for instance [sch_ship_date] over to the column and do the same for the second parent group
   8. Once that is done you will delete the first two columns since they were extra created during the adding parent groups process
   9. So now you should only have one table that contains your two parent groups in order and an empty details field (your third row)
   10. Now since the groups are embedded technically  you will delete the values in the fields but do not delete the groups you added.
   11. After there are no values in your table but you still have three rows you will insert a rectangle for each row. Each rectangle will be a place holder for your data set fields.
   12. For the fields your data set fields you want to set there properties as "keep contents together on a single page"